# How to create multiline edittext with scroll view within activity?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-edittext

I want edittext which will have 3 lines and if the edittext content exceeds 3 lines limit then  vertical scrollbar should be visible to user.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

may work 100%

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="int number" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `inputType="textMultiLine"` and set  `android:lines="3"` like:

```
<EditText
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:lines="3" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
/>
```

Comment: When adding android:scrollbars="vertical", Edittext changes its height on keyboard opening (in my case its android:layout_height="match_parent"). What can cause such problem?

Answer (score 4):

I think this question is more about adding Multiline editText inside scrollview.

Inside scrollview, If your EditText has more text you wont be able to scroll inside, rather whole page will scroll.

You can achieve this with help of TouchListener.

```
edtDescription = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_description);

    edtDescription.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    edtDescription.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
    edtDescription.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);
    edtDescription.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());

    edtDescription.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            if ((motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) != 0 && (motionEvent.getActionMasked() & MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) != 0)
            {
                view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In you edit Text just add

```
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    android:maxLines="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have tried with ? :

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_note"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLines="3"
            >
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code snippets...you will get your requirement right. And one thing to note, you have to give hard coded Height of ScrollView...I give here as 70dip.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false" />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

if textview lines exceeds two line scrollview will scroll

```
if (mTvContacts.getLayout().getLineCount() >= 2) {
    if (scrollContactsHeight == 0)
        scrollContactsHeight = scrollContacts.getHeight();

        scrollContacts.getLayoutParams().height = scrollContactsHeight * 2;
} else {
    if (scrollContactsHeight == 0)
        scrollContacts.getLayoutParams().height = scrollContacts.getHeight();
    else
        scrollContacts.getLayoutParams().height = scrollContacts.getHeight() / 2;
}


 <ScrollView  
        android:id="@+id/scrollContacts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"           
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"        
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTo"  
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgAddContacts">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContacts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="wfd"
            android:textColor="#000" />

</ScrollView>
```